# Yii2: set text field's value when an item from a dropdownlist is selected

Tags: yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-basic-app

I have the following code on my form:

```
    <?php
     $unitPrices = ArrayHelper::map(Item::find()->where('isApproved and 
     vendor_id=:id', [':id' => $vendorId])->all(),'id','unitPrice'); 
    ?>
```

- this gives me a map called unitPrices where the key-value pairing is id-unitPrice

  ```
  <?= $form->field($model, 'item_id')->dropDownList(
  ArrayHelper::map(Item::find()->where('isApproved and vendor_id=:id', [':id' => $vendorId])->all(),'id','itemCode','description'), 

      [   

          'prompt'=>'--Select Item--',

          'id'=>'item_selected',

          'onchange' => '$("#priceOnLine").val($unitPrices[item_id_value]);',
      ])

  ?>
  ```
- what I want to do is when an item is selected from the dropdownlist, it also sets the value of a text field called priceOnLine using the unitPrices map where the id is the value of the selected item from the dropdownlist.
- I tried setting the text field to a static value (100), and it works but I can't figure out how to set it using the map.

  ```
  'onchange' => '$("#priceOnLine").val(100);',
  ```

Thanks in advance for the help :D

Comment: Are you sure this $unitPrices[item_id_value] gives a value?

Comment: you want the price of the selected item from the dropdown to be inserted in a text field? is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Hi @Sfili_81, actually I believe it doesn't. I haven't figured out how to access the map from within the onchange portion of the code. The item_id_value is just a pseudocode to represent how I want to access the map using the selected id value as index.

Comment: Hi @Muhammad Omer Aslam, yes that is my goal. I want to get the id of the selected item from the dropdown and since the map and the contents of the dropdown are virtually the same, I want to use the selected id to get the corresponding price on the map

Comment: hey, did it worked for you?

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the text of the selected option you can add the following script on the top of your view and remove the `'onchange' => '$("#priceOnLine").val($unitPrices[item_id_value]);',` from your `dropDown()`

```
<?php 

$js=<<<JS
    $("#item_selected").on("change",function(){
       $("#priceOnLine").val(($(this).find("option:selected").text()));
    });
JS;

$this->registerJs($js,\yii\web\View::POS_READY);
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Oooh I'll test this out maybe later or tomorrow. So basically I can't do it without js? Can you please explain why the onchange doesn't work? I'd like to understand why a static value works but variables don't. Thanks!

Comment: what i have used is also triggering onchange but there is a difference between your and mine implementation, the way you are specifying is incorrect because it wont access the **currently selected** value of the dropdown BUT the static value @luigilopez you can notice `$(this).find("option:selected")` this line which uses javascript to acces the currently selected value, and the main reason for my apprach is to keep the code separated , the javascript and the HTML, so it is always easy to troubleshoot and edit